# Downloading images from custom registry with go-dockerclient hangs

Tags: go, docker, docker-registry

I cannot seem to pull from a custom registry. Am I doing it wrong? I know those images exist, I can download them manually.

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/fsouza/go-dockerclient"
    log "github.com/Sirupsen/logrus"
)

func main() {
    log.SetFormatter(&log.JSONFormatter{})
    log.Infoln("pulling remote images.")
    pull_images()
    log.Infoln("done.")
}

var (
    gcr = "gcr.io/google_containers/"

    fluentd = docker.PullImageOptions{
        Repository: "fluentd-elasticsearch",
        Registry: gcr,
        RawJSONStream: true,
    }
    local_images = []docker.PullImageOptions{fluentd,{...}} // there is a long list of image, truncated for example.
)

func pull_images() {
    // empty config as it is not needed at this point.
    auth := docker.AuthConfiguration{}

    client, err := docker.NewClientFromEnv()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    for _, image := range local_images {
        log.Infof("pulling %s%s", image.Registry, image.Repository)
        err = client.PullImage(image, auth)
        if err != nil {
            log.Warnln(err)
        }
    }
}
```

It works if I specify the `docker.io` registry and use the Ubuntu image, but it's not working with the Google one. I can manually pull images with `docker pull -a gcr.io/google_containers/fluentd-elasticsearch`, so I know it exists and is actively available. I haven't logged into the Google registry with my docker client, so I know that anonymous pulls are allowed.

Comment: Your example code worked for me. Go1.5.1 linux/amd64 : http://pastebin.com/XwfV0MY8

Comment: Can you `kill -ABRT <pid>` your program to get us the stack traces please? (see http://pro-tips-dot-com.tumblr.com/post/47677612115/kill-a-hung-go-process-and-print-stack-traces)

Comment: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/13250025/

Comment: @mynameismevin From your log it seems that it's actually pulling from the registry. Are you sure that you've waited enough time so that the image has enough time to download? Also, can you check your network activity while the script is running to see if it's actually performing the pull?

Comment: That fixed it. Closing.

Answer (score 0):

There were networking issues that were preventing the download.